# How to claculate density probabilistic function between images in python

Tags: python, numpy, covariance, mean

I have converted 1000 images with 28*28 dimensions into one matrix in python. Hence, I have a matrix with 1000*784 dimension called `X`. I want to find the density probability function between these images. I found [`pypr.clustering.gmm.mulnormpdf(X, MU, SIGMA)`](http://pypr.sourceforge.net/auto/pypr.clustering.html). 
*Mu* is the mean between images calculated by [`np.mean`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.mean.html), and *SIGMA* is the covariance matrix between images calculated by [`SIGMA=np.cov(X.T)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html). 
When I do the following:

`mu=X.mean(0) 
 np.cov(X)
 pdf1=gmm.mulnormpdf(X, MU, SIGMA)`

I will get:

```
pdf1=[nan,nan,nan,...nan]
```

why? It cannot claculate pdf.